# Why only call constructor one time?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have tried my code to find how `copy constructor` works. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B{
public:
    B(){
        cout << "B()\n";
    }
    B(const B& b){
        cout << "B(const B&)\n";
    }
    ~B(){
        cout << "~B()\n";
    }
};

int main(){
    B b = B();

    return 0;
}
```

For the code `B b = B()`, I think the process is like this:

1. Call constructor `B()`, print *B()*, return a **temporary** object of type `B`;
2. Call the **copy constructor** `B(const B&)`, pass the returned object in step 1 as arguments, print *B(const B&)*, initialize variable `b`.

But my code just outputs `B()`, which means no `copy constructor` is called. What is the problem?

Comment: The key phrase you're looking for to answer this question is "[copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)".

Comment: @Insilico But I disable the **optimization** option of my **VC++ Compiler**.